# Sample space for sampling from (a large) student population...?

Tags: probability

10% students left handed. 30% blue eyed. 5% both left handed and blue eyed. Two students are chosen at random and whether or not each was blue eyed or left handed is noted. Assuming population of students is large, describe a sample space for this experiment and assign appropriate probabilities. Also what is the significance of the assumption of a large population?

So is this okay for a sample space?

Let sample point $w = (x,y)$ where $x =$ $left$ $handed$ and $x\prime$ $=$ $not$ $left$ $handed$, 
$y = blue$ $eyed$ and $y\prime =$ $not$ $blue$ $eyed$.

Then $sample$ $space$ $= {(x,y) (x\prime,y)  (x,y\prime) (x\prime,y\prime)}^2$ (because two students are picked).

So probabilities for a student to be left handed is $P(w_x=x)=\frac{1}{10}$, a student to be blue eyed is $P(w_y=y)=\frac{3}{10}$, and for a student to be both is $P(w=x,y)=\frac{5}{100}$. If you want the probabilties for two students you just square these probabilties.

And I think large population means we can neglect that fact that the probabilities will be slightly different once we have to pick the second student as depending on what the first was would alter the calculation, but since we're picking a small sample from a large population the difference in the two calculations is negligible.

Is this a correct way to answer this question?